# OOM from iterating over very large memory map

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-memory, out-of-memory, mmap

I'm writing a simulator that relies on generating a (potentially) very large problem domain. As the data can't fit in RAM, I use 4 four memory mapped files to hold it.  This is a 64-bit application running on 64-bit Linux with 8GB of RAM.

My application iterates over the memory maps in multiple threads and performs read and write operations on them.  However my program causes an OOM shortly after starting (no thrashing occurs):

```
[  683.899682] Purging GPU memory, 25 pages freed, 12838 pages still pinned.
[  683.899683] 50 and 0 pages still available in the bound and unbound GPU page lists.
[  683.899732] Purging GPU memory, 0 pages freed, 12838 pages still pinned.
[  683.899732] 50 and 0 pages still available in the bound and unbound GPU page lists.
[  683.901441] gnome-shell invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x240c0d0(GFP_TEMPORARY|__GFP_COMP|__GFP_ZERO), order=3, oom_score_adj=0
[  683.901443] gnome-shell cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
[  683.901446] CPU: 0 PID: 1714 Comm: gnome-shell Not tainted 4.8.8-300.fc25.x86_64 #1
[  683.901447] Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 13 9350/0PWNCR, BIOS 1.4.4 06/14/2016
[  683.901449]  0000000000000286 000000006699dcf4 ffff8c743292b588 ffffffff863e5dbd
[  683.901451]  ffff8c743292b748 ffff8c73d7431f00 ffff8c743292b5f0 ffffffff8624c1f8
[  683.901453]  000000006699dcf4 000000006699dcf4 ffffffff86e9cac0 0000000000000015
[  683.901454] Call Trace:
[  683.901459]  [<ffffffff863e5dbd>] dump_stack+0x63/0x86
[  683.901460]  [<ffffffff8624c1f8>] dump_header+0x5c/0x1d5
[  683.901463]  [<ffffffff861bd90c>] oom_kill_process+0x20c/0x3d0
[  683.901465]  [<ffffffff860aacfe>] ? has_capability_noaudit+0x1e/0x30
[  683.901466]  [<ffffffff861bde76>] out_of_memory+0x356/0x440
[  683.901468]  [<ffffffff861c3df0>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0xe90/0xeb0
[  683.901470]  [<ffffffff8621a055>] alloc_pages_current+0x95/0x140
[  683.901472]  [<ffffffff861e54be>] kmalloc_order_trace+0x2e/0xd0
[  683.901508]  [<ffffffffc03962b6>] ? gen9_read32+0x166/0x3a0 [i915]
[  683.901510]  [<ffffffff8622782d>] __kmalloc+0x1cd/0x1f0
[  683.901525]  [<ffffffffc036eaae>] ? alloc_gen8_temp_bitmaps+0x2e/0x80 [i915]
[  683.901537]  [<ffffffffc036eac7>] alloc_gen8_temp_bitmaps+0x47/0x80 [i915]
[  683.901552]  [<ffffffffc036eb9c>] gen8_alloc_va_range_3lvl+0x9c/0x9f0 [i915]
[  683.901553]  [<ffffffff861b896b>] ? find_lock_entry+0x5b/0x140
[  683.901555]  [<ffffffff86411003>] ? swiotlb_map_sg_attrs+0x53/0x130
[  683.901567]  [<ffffffffc036f88c>] gen8_alloc_va_range+0x23c/0x470 [i915]
[  683.901580]  [<ffffffffc0370e5b>] i915_vma_bind+0x9b/0x180 [i915]
[  683.901593]  [<ffffffffc03774fb>] i915_gem_object_do_pin+0x86b/0xa60 [i915]
[  683.901606]  [<ffffffffc037771d>] i915_gem_object_pin+0x2d/0x30 [i915]
[  683.901618]  [<ffffffffc0365acf>] i915_gem_execbuffer_reserve_vma.isra.20+0x9f/0x180 [i915]
[  683.901633]  [<ffffffffc0365f3b>] i915_gem_execbuffer_reserve.isra.21+0x38b/0x3b0 [i915]
[  683.901646]  [<ffffffffc03671d8>] i915_gem_do_execbuffer.isra.24+0x6b8/0x1200 [i915]
[  683.901648]  [<ffffffff861b87d0>] ? find_get_entry+0x20/0x160
[  683.901650]  [<ffffffff861d9b99>] ? shmem_getpage_gfp+0xd9/0xc90
[  683.901661]  [<ffffffffc0368944>] i915_gem_execbuffer2+0x104/0x260 [i915]
[  683.901691]  [<ffffffffc0250fa0>] drm_ioctl+0x200/0x4f0 [drm]
[  683.901704]  [<ffffffffc0368840>] ? i915_gem_execbuffer+0x330/0x330 [i915]
[  683.901705]  [<ffffffff862692ff>] ? dput+0x21f/0x260
[  683.901707]  [<ffffffff86264cd3>] do_vfs_ioctl+0xa3/0x5f0
[  683.901708]  [<ffffffff86265299>] SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
[  683.901710]  [<ffffffff868027b2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x1a/0xa4
[  683.901711] Mem-Info:
[  683.901714] active_anon:95440 inactive_anon:114637 isolated_anon:0
                active_file:1284097 inactive_file:231741 isolated_file:0
                unevictable:31 dirty:107 writeback:155137 unstable:0
                slab_reclaimable:34416 slab_unreclaimable:15787
                mapped:1373800 shmem:49734 pagetables:32919 bounce:0
                free:26810 free_pcp:0 free_cma:0
[  683.901717] Node 0 active_anon:381760kB inactive_anon:458548kB active_file:5136388kB inactive_file:926964kB unevictable:124kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB mapped:5495200kB dirty:428kB writeback:620548kB shmem:0kB shmem_thp: 0kB shmem_pmdmapped: 0kB anon_thp: 198936kB writeback_tmp:0kB unstable:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
[  683.901718] Node 0 DMA free:15872kB min:132kB low:164kB high:196kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:15980kB managed:15896kB mlocked:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:24kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
[  683.901720] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 1829 7809 7809 7809
[  683.901723] Node 0 DMA32 free:39676kB min:15796kB low:19744kB high:23692kB active_anon:2196kB inactive_anon:180kB active_file:1467288kB inactive_file:152024kB unevictable:0kB writepending:120700kB present:1958284kB managed:1892644kB mlocked:0kB slab_reclaimable:34852kB slab_unreclaimable:4228kB kernel_stack:32kB pagetables:27600kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
[  683.901725] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 5980 5980 5980
[  683.901727] Node 0 Normal free:51692kB min:51648kB low:64560kB high:77472kB active_anon:379564kB inactive_anon:458368kB active_file:3669100kB inactive_file:774940kB unevictable:124kB writepending:500276kB present:6275072kB managed:6128020kB mlocked:124kB slab_reclaimable:102812kB slab_unreclaimable:58896kB kernel_stack:8288kB pagetables:104076kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
[  683.901729] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
[  683.901731] Node 0 DMA: 0*4kB 0*8kB 2*16kB (U) 1*32kB (U) 3*64kB (U) 2*128kB (U) 0*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 1*2048kB (M) 3*4096kB (M) = 15872kB
[  683.901738] Node 0 DMA32: 6599*4kB (UME) 1573*8kB (UM) 51*16kB (UM) 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 39796kB
[  683.901744] Node 0 Normal: 11012*4kB (UMEH) 955*8kB (UMH) 11*16kB (H) 1*32kB (H) 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 51896kB
[  683.901750] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
[  683.901751] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
[  683.901752] 1565598 total pagecache pages
[  683.901752] 0 pages in swap cache
[  683.901753] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
[  683.901754] Free swap  = 8126460kB
[  683.901754] Total swap = 8126460kB
[  683.901754] 2062334 pages RAM
[  683.901755] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
[  683.901755] 53194 pages reserved
[  683.901755] 0 pages cma reserved
[  683.901756] 0 pages hwpoisoned
[  683.901756] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
[  683.901771] [  771]     0   771    19588     1983      34       3        0             0 systemd-journal
[  683.901773] [  802]     0   802    32268     1616      29       3        0             0 lvmetad
[  683.901775] [  808]     0   808    11972     1901      25       3        0         -1000 systemd-udevd
[  683.901778] [  987]     0   987    13888      834      27       3        0         -1000 auditd
[  683.901779] [  998]     0   998    21136      443      12       3        0             0 audispd
[  683.901781] [ 1001]     0  1001    10907      520      26       3        0             0 sedispatch
[  683.901782] [ 1011]     0  1011     1104      180       8       3        0             0 rngd
[  683.901783] [ 1012]     0  1012     4220      343      13       3        0             0 alsactl
[  683.901784] [ 1013]     0  1013    98858     1754      45       3        0             0 accounts-daemon
[  683.901785] [ 1015]     0  1015    10882     1188      23       3        0             0 bluetoothd
[  683.901786] [ 1017]     0  1017   104437     2240      73       4        0             0 ModemManager
[  683.901787] [ 1018]   172  1018    46710      823      28       3        0             0 rtkit-daemon
[  683.901788] [ 1020]     0  1020     1642      478       9       3        0             0 mcelog
[  683.901790] [ 1022]    81  1022    14507     1493      27       3        0          -900 dbus-daemon
[  683.901791] [ 1026]   990  1026    28014      782      25       3        0             0 chronyd
[  683.901792] [ 1036]     0  1036    51991      804      38       3        0             0 gssproxy
[  683.901794] [ 1048]     0  1048   167266     8834     105       4        0             0 firewalld
[  683.901795] [ 1050]     0  1050    12558     1987      28       3        0             0 systemd-logind
[  683.901797] [ 1052]    70  1052    12579      990      28       3        0             0 avahi-daemon
[  683.901798] [ 1057]   995  1057   133403     3831      56       3        0             0 polkitd
[  683.901799] [ 1059]     0  1059   111734     2268      64       3        0             0 abrtd
[  683.901800] [ 1066]    70  1066    12547       89      27       3        0             0 avahi-daemon
[  683.901801] [ 1086]     0  1086   156436     3838      85       3        0             0 NetworkManager
[  683.901802] [ 1110]     0  1110   228634     8292     174       4        0             0 libvirtd
[  683.901803] [ 1122]     0  1122   102461     2029      47       3        0             0 gdm
[  683.901804] [ 1125]     0  1125    33234      810      19       3        0             0 crond
[  683.901805] [ 1126]     0  1126     6490      534      19       3        0             0 atd
[  683.901806] [ 1213]     0  1213    93009     2339      67       4        0             0 gdm-session-wor
[  683.901807] [ 1222]     0  1222    16576     1873      36       3        0             0 wpa_supplicant
[  683.901808] [ 1236]    42  1236    16516     1785      36       3        0             0 systemd
[  683.901809] [ 1238]    42  1238    24758      780      47       3        0             0 (sd-pam)
[  683.901810] [ 1242]    42  1242   112470     2665      94       3        0             0 gdm-wayland-ses
[  683.901811] [ 1244]    42  1244    14131     1121      28       3        0             0 dbus-daemon
[  683.901812] [ 1247]    42  1247   172808     3320     110       4        0             0 gnome-session-b
[  683.901813] [ 1255]    42  1255   403569    27848     305       5        0             0 gnome-shell
[  683.901814] [ 1270]     0  1270   107218     2323      53       4        0             0 upowerd
[  683.901816] [ 1277]     0  1277   261220     3428     344       4        0             0 abrt-dump-journ
[  683.901817] [ 1279]     0  1279   262477     3538     345       4        0             0 abrt-dump-journ
[  683.901818] [ 1338]    99  1338    12274       92      26       3        0             0 dnsmasq
[  683.901819] [ 1339]     0  1339    12267       92      26       3        0             0 dnsmasq
[  683.901820] [ 1420]    42  1420    62218    11072     107       3        0             0 Xwayland
[  683.901822] [ 1426]    42  1426    86174     1417      36       3        0             0 at-spi-bus-laun
[  683.901823] [ 1431]    42  1431    14074      920      27       3        0             0 dbus-daemon
[  683.901824] [ 1434]    42  1434    55841     1513      42       4        0             0 at-spi2-registr
[  683.901825] [ 1440]    42  1440   164934     2682      84       4        0             0 pulseaudio
[  683.901826] [ 1453]    42  1453   115040     2138      39       3        0             0 ibus-daemon
[  683.901827] [ 1456]    42  1456    95634     1424      38       3        0             0 ibus-dconf
[  683.901828] [ 1459]    42  1459   126126     6717     129       3        0             0 ibus-x11
[  683.901829] [ 1465]    42  1465   109804     2173      59       3        0             0 xdg-permission-
[  683.901830] [ 1473]     0  1473   196027    18444     150       3        0             0 packagekitd
[  683.901831] [ 1477]    42  1477   302617     9107     200       5        0             0 gnome-settings-
[  683.901832] [ 1497]    42  1497    77184     1362      34       3        0             0 ibus-engine-sim
[  683.901833] [ 1538]   993  1538   103715     2539      54       3        0             0 colord
[  683.901834] [ 1583]     0  1583    98709     2395      77       3        0             0 gdm-session-wor
[  683.901835] [ 1592]     0  1592    21780     4717      46       3        0             0 dhclient
[  683.901836] [ 1641]     0  1641    84698     2398      50       4        0             0 nm-openvpn-serv
[  683.901837] [ 1645]   988  1645    17970     1854      40       3        0             0 openvpn
[  683.901838] [ 1648]  1000  1648    16517     1756      34       4        0             0 systemd
[  683.901839] [ 1656]  1000  1656    24794      801      47       3        0             0 (sd-pam)
[  683.901840] [ 1666]  1000  1666   118117     2041      44       3        0             0 gnome-keyring-d
[  683.901841] [ 1669]  1000  1669   112470     2807      97       3        0             0 gdm-wayland-ses
[  683.901843] [ 1671]  1000  1671    14340     1294      30       3        0             0 dbus-daemon
[  683.901844] [ 1674]  1000  1674   172877     3440     114       4        0             0 gnome-session-b
[  683.901845] [ 1686]  1000  1686    98759     1747      42       3        0             0 gvfsd
[  683.901846] [ 1691]  1000  1691   104451     1327      37       3        0             0 gvfsd-fuse
[  683.901847] [ 1714]  1000  1714   447111    39711     335       5        0             0 gnome-shell
[  683.901848] [ 1729]  1000  1729    62884    11611     111       3        0             0 Xwayland
[  683.901849] [ 1735]  1000  1735    86177     1474      36       4        0             0 at-spi-bus-laun
[  683.901850] [ 1740]  1000  1740    14106     1108      29       3        0             0 dbus-daemon
[  683.901851] [ 1743]  1000  1743    55841     1516      46       3        0             0 at-spi2-registr
[  683.901852] [ 1749]  1000  1749   173283     3029     102       4        0             0 pulseaudio
[  683.901853] [ 1765]  1000  1765   221322     8359     193       4        0             0 gnome-shell-cal
[  683.901854] [ 1766]  1000  1766   115001     2100      41       4        0             0 ibus-daemon
[  683.901855] [ 1770]  1000  1770    95645     1397      37       3        0             0 ibus-dconf
[  683.901855] [ 1772]  1000  1772   126126     6529     126       4        0             0 ibus-x11
[  683.901856] [ 1782]  1000  1782   229523     9384     213       4        0             0 evolution-sourc
[  683.901857] [ 1785]  1000  1785   109804     2197      62       4        0             0 xdg-permission-
[  683.901858] [ 1794]  1000  1794   105580     2119      55       3        0             0 gvfs-udisks2-vo
[  683.901859] [ 1801]     0  1801    97029     2083      54       3        0             0 udisksd
[  683.901860] [ 1808]  1000  1808   222729     7688     172       4        0             0 goa-daemon
[  683.901861] [ 1811]  1000  1811    98629     1391      40       3        0             0 gvfs-gphoto2-vo
[  683.901862] [ 1817]  1000  1817    94552     1372      35       3        0             0 gvfs-goa-volume
[  683.901864] [ 1827]  1000  1827   136872     2734     108       3        0             0 goa-identity-se
[  683.901865] [ 1829]  1000  1829    96354     1300      38       3        0             0 gvfs-mtp-volume
[  683.901866] [ 1836]  1000  1836   122361     2095      53       4        0             0 gvfs-afc-volume
[  683.901867] [ 1848]  1000  1848   322422    10974     240       5        0             0 gnome-settings-
[  683.901868] [ 1861]  1000  1861   269205    10731     229       4        0             0 evolution-calen
[  683.901870] [ 1889]  1000  1889    77225     1429      35       3        0             0 ibus-engine-sim
[  683.901871] [ 1981]  1000  1981   290746     9893     206       4        0             0 evolution-calen
[  683.901872] [ 1993]  1000  1993   163552     5140      89       4        0             0 tracker-miner-f
[  683.901873] [ 1995]  1000  1995   158399     4233      78       4        0             0 tracker-miner-a
[  683.901874] [ 1999]  1000  1999   185785     4846      96       4        0             0 tracker-extract
[  683.901875] [ 2010]  1000  2010   140701     4027      79       4        0             0 tracker-miner-u
[  683.901876] [ 2011]     0  2011    52365     1984      53       3        0             0 cupsd
[  683.901878] [ 2017]  1000  2017    46916     1268      27       4        0             0 dconf-service
[  683.901879] [ 2021]  1000  2021   265817     9429     221       4        0             0 evolution-addre
[  683.901880] [ 2023]  1000  2023   272624     9896     198       4        0             0 evolution-calen
[  683.901881] [ 2027]  1000  2027   133874     3898      60       4        0             0 tracker-store
[  683.901882] [ 2043]  1000  2043   160491     3462     122       4        0             0 gsd-printer
[  683.901883] [ 2051]  1000  2051   168185     6168     137       3        0             0 abrt-applet
[  683.901884] [ 2054]  1000  2054    83177     4194     112       3        0             0 seapplet
[  683.901885] [ 2071]  1000  2071   308067     9309     203       4        0             0 evolution-addre
[  683.901886] [ 2127]  1000  2127   657040    48104     313       6        0             0 insync
[  683.901887] [ 2133]     0  2133    85913     2519      64       4        0          -900 abrt-dbus
[  683.901888] [ 2163]  1000  2163    45120     1422      39       3        0             0 gconfd-2
[  683.901890] [ 2200]  1000  2200    77445     1596      35       4        0             0 gvfsd-metadata
[  683.901891] [ 2215]  1000  2215   203657    11515     145       4        0             0 gnome-terminal-
[  683.901892] [ 2235]  1000  2235   117765     1710      47       3        0             0 gvfsd-trash
[  683.901893] [ 2309]  1000  2309    30789     1208      15       3        0             0 bash
[  683.901895] [ 2397]  1000  2397   170605    13763     148       4        0             0 gnome-system-mo
[  683.901896] [ 3036]  1000  3036 12251152  1306699   23712      50        0             0 SyrenProcessor_
[  683.901897] [ 3042]  1000  3042    30763     1084      14       3        0             0 bash
[  683.901899] [ 3122]  1000  3122    30267      247      12       3        0             0 dmesg
[  683.901900] Out of memory: Kill process 3036 (SyrenProcessor_) score 329 or sacrifice child
[  683.901928] Killed process 3036 (SyrenProcessor_) total-vm:49004608kB, anon-rss:1368kB, file-rss:5226416kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

As you can see my application is holding ~50GB in the memory maps.

I was under the assumption that when my app accessed data in the virtual address space, Linux would work out which page the address sits in, and if it's not already in RAM, trigger a page fault to have the page pulled from disk.  In that assumption there would only be as many pages in RAM as there are threads accessing the memory map - I know in reality Linux caches as many pages as it can to improve performance but Linux should discard less active pages as required, so they shouldn't be a problem.  Which is why I thought you couldn't get OOM errors when using memory maps (assuming you have the disk space and don't exceed the 64-bit address range).  This obviously isn't the case, so can someone correct my assumption?

In the last line `anon-rss:1368kB` seems reasonable as my application uses very little RAM for it's own functionality, and `file-rss:5226416kB` shows that it's trying to bring 5.2 GB of the memory map data into RAM - and there would have been that much available for it.

So why was the OOM triggered?

Comment: I'd really like to see this answered, because it's pretty interesting. (My edit is mostly to bump it.) Can you post the code, or a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example of the code  you're using to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Linux allows it's memory to be over allocated, on the grounds that most programs ask for more memory than they actually need, and then worries when it finds it **has** actually over allocated it's memory and launches OOM killer.

sysctl vm.overcommit_memory can be helpful, setting it to 2 will cause the OS to give you an error when you do something it can't handle, rather than hoping for the best.

Having a swap partition/file big enough to hold your data may allow things to work as expected.

Alternately, this could be an issue with the files themselves being too big, so mmap2() may be a better choice.